# How to apply a grid of control points to deform the image in python

Tags: python, image, image-registration

I am beginners in Python; nevertheless, I lately started using this language for an important research project on medical image processing, image registration.

Actually, for free-form registration we have a grid of control-points distributed over the image here named matrix Fi. The displacement of each control-point from its original location is represented by the matrix Ro. Each element of Fi and Ro is a 2-member array like [x1,y1]. Dimension of 2D Image, the Grid and also the original spacing among control points are demonstrated with Mx, My, Nx, Ny, Sx, Sy, respectively.

[The cubic B-Spline interpolation equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG4nT.jpg)

I want to know how to apply the aforementioned cubic B-Spline equation to this grid of control points to create a DDF (Dense Displacement Field, i.e. displacement in x and y coordination for each pixel in the image) to finally deform the image **using NumPy or TensorFlow** in an efficient way. Currently, my following iterative algorithm is too slow.

```py
for x in range(Mx-1):
    for y in range(My-1):
        Px=x//Sx;Py=y//Sy
        i=Px-1;j=Py-1
        u=x/Sx-Px;v=y/Sy-Py
        DDF[x, y] = 0
        for l in range(4):
            for m in range(4):
                DDF[x,y] = DDF[x,y] + B3(l,u)*B3(m,v)*Ro[i+l,j+m]
```

I cannot use ready-to-use interpolation functions like those in SciPy, since I have a annotation-file  for each image where some landmarks are specified, and I need to know the location of each landmark after the deformation  in the warped image.

Thanks in advance to help me.

Comment: Hi! Please paste your code as text, not pictures.

Comment: Hi! It was done. Do you have any idea about the problem?

Comment: You should also probably format properly the equation (using [this image generator](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) for example) and include it as a clean picture. I have no idea about your question though:)